# NestJSx CRUD: excluding nested fields from GET response

Tags: crud, nestjs

I know I'm able to exclude direct-child fields, but can I do that in a nested fashion? I'm trying to make sure the field "password" is always removed, no matter how "nested" it is.

So instead of just being able to do

```
  query: {
    exclude: ['password']
```

I'd like to do

```
  query: {
    exclude: ['user.password']
```

Comment: This might be relevant as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59697325/4694994

Comment: Thanks @KimKern, that is indeed a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: you can specify it in the "join" of the corresponding controller. E.g. from the example above, I put this in the controller that was loading "user" as a child object:

```
query: {
    join: {
      user: {exclude: ['password'] }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the best solution for that is using `class-transformer` to manipulate your output based on specific conditions. And then use for that an `Interceptor` that will valid if collection or response is some kind of type, and use `serialize` method or `classToPlain` to execute all of the `decorators` that are pinned to entity.